# Filter a list of integer ranges by both a maximum overlap percentage and value

Tags: python, list, range, overlap

I have a list of ranges such as:

```
[12-48,40-80,60-105,110-130,75-400]
```

And I need to filter out or remove the ranges which overlap more than x digits (So overlap more than 10 for example) and/or overlap more than x% (Lets say 20%) of the smallest of the compared ranges.

At the moment I use a for loop to check each range at a time and compare it to the next to see whether they overlap past my stated limits, and if so, remove it. This does not work as with in the example I show I get this result:

```
[12-48,75-400]
```

The range [40-80] should not have been removed because it does not overlap with our 2 remaining ranges past the limits but because it overlapped [60-105] and was the smaller of the 2, it was removed. The correct remaining ranges should be:

```
[12-48,40-80,75-400]
```

I do not think a simple for loop is the solution here but I am at a loss. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

#### Current Code

The parts with GeneA/GenePrev/GeneAND are how I calculate the % overlap and can be ignored.

```
        start = int(key.split(',')[0])
        stop = int(key.split(',')[1])
        length = stop - start
        if First == True:
            Both_Frames[key] = value
            First = False
            GeneA[start:stop] = [1] * (stop - start)
            GenePrev = GeneA
            PrevStart = start
            PrevStop = stop
            prevlength = PrevStop - PrevStart
        else:
            GeneA[start:stop] = [1] * (stop - start)
            Gene_AND = GenePrev & GeneA

            if start == PrevStart:
                GenePrev = GeneA
                
                ######Need to delete item from dictionary which is overlapping
                Both_Frames.popitem(last=False)
                Both_Frames[key] = value
                PrevStart = start
                PrevStop = stop
                prevlength = PrevStop - PrevStart
            elif start >= PrevStart and stop <= PrevStop:
           
                continue
            elif  np.count_nonzero(Gene_AND) <= (length * OverLapPercentage) and np.count_nonzero(Gene_AND) <= OverLapNT:
                GenePrev = GeneA
                Both_Frames[key] = value
                PrevStart = start
                PrevStop = stop
                prevlength = PrevStop - PrevStart

            elif np.count_nonzero(Gene_AND) >= (length * OverLapPercentage) or np.count_nonzero(Gene_AND) >= OverLapNT:
                if length > prevlength:
                    GenePrev = GeneA
                 
                    Both_Frames.popitem(last=False)
                    Both_Frames[key] = value
                    PrevStart = start
                    PrevStop = stop
                    prevlength = PrevStop - PrevStart
```

Comment: Could you edit and add the actual code you are using that you described? Right now you're just asking us to solve this problem for you.

Comment: It is a monstrosity - Added to the bottom

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why can't we have `[12-48,40-80,110-130]` as the final result? The overlap between these ranges is also not more than 10?

Comment: 110-130 falls well within 75-400. I should have stated that if range falls within another then it is also removed.

Comment: What is "overlap percentage" defined as? Does it mean 20% of the range between the largest and smallest numbers in the two tuples of interest? // Can we assume that the "data" (list of tuples) is "sorted" that is, we are only comparing between two adjacent indices? // Overall could you better define what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry for my unexplained calculation but basically 'maximum overlap percentage' means the percentage of overlap between the two 'target' ranges based on the shortest range. For example, two ranges - 80-120 and 100-200. The short range is 80-120 so we calculate the overlap for that range. The overlap for this range is 50% (80-120 = 40 and 100-120 is 20. 20 is 50% of 40).

Comment: The ranges are sorted, so every 'next' ranges start is past the start of the previous range but this can happen [40-100,60-80]. I am not sure how else to explain via typing :L

Answer (score 1):

I may have a convoluted solution for you:

First, I convert your ranges to a `list` of `tuples` of `int`:

```py
import pandas as pd


r = ["12-48", "40-80", "60-105", "110-130", "75-400"]
r = [tuple(map(int, z.split("-"))) for z in r]

# [(12, 48), (40, 80), (60, 105), (110, 130), (75, 400)]
```

Then, I iterate all the ranges and remove any that are entirely encapsulated by another range. E.g: `(110, 130)` is within `(75, 400)`:

```py
hold = []
for idx1 in range(len(r)):
    start_1, stop_1 = r[idx1]
    for idx2, (start_2, stop_2) in enumerate(r):
        if idx1 == idx2:
            continue
        if start_2 < start_1 and stop_1 < stop_2:
            hold.append(idx1)

while hold:
    del r[hold.pop()]

# [(12, 48), (40, 80), (60, 105), (75, 400)]
```

Finally, using a `pandas.DataFrame` I calculate the overlap and percentage overlap; label the rows that meet your exclusion criteria (overlap > 10 and % > 0.2). These rows are then removed in reverse order, and the overlaps are tested again after each removal until no more rows can be removed.

The DataFrame is then converted back into a list of strings in the same format they were supplied in.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=["start", "stop"]).sort_values("start")

df["length"] = df["stop"] - df["start"]
df["bool_1"], df["bool_2"] = True, True

while any(df["bool_1"].eq(True) & df["bool_2"].eq(True)):
    df["overlap"] = df["stop"] - df["start"].shift(-1)
    df["pc"] = df["overlap"] / df["length"]

    df["bool_1"] = df["overlap"] > 10
    df["bool_2"] = df["pc"] > 0.2
    for i, row in df.sort_index(ascending=False).iterrows():
        if row["bool_1"] == row["bool_2"] and row["bool_1"] is not False:
            df.drop(i, inplace=True)
            break

result = df["start"].astype("str").str.cat(df["stop"].astype("str"), sep="-").to_list()

# ['12-48', '40-80', '75-400']
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay - This did partly work but there is still one instance it fails on.  If we had a list such as [(0, 90), (27, 99), (28, 229), (126, 291), (138, 379)]], it would filter out 0-90 instead of 27-99. Meaning we are left with [(27-99),(138-379)] as the remaining list of ranges.

Comment: Also it should also remove the shortest of any two 'overlapping' ranges.